# Stack, Pop and Add

Tags: python

This `calculate` function should work like this

```
calculate((1, 2, '+', 3, '*')) which return 9
1. take 1, push 1   # stack is [1]
2. take 2, push 2   #stack is [1, 2]
3. take '+', pop 2, pop 1, calculate 1+2 = 3, push 3 #stack is [3]
4. take 3, push 3 #stack is [3, 3]
5. take '*', pop 3, pop 3, calculate 3 * 3 = 9, push 9 #stack is [9]
6. input empty, pop 9, return 9
```

I don't know how do I use the string '+' here to add 1 and 2 together. Seems impossible.

Here is my code. We suppose to convert the tuple and put it into a list then pop the first 2 number out then with combine with any binary operators `'+', '-', '*', '/'`

```
def calculate(inputs):  #(1, 2, '+', 3, '/')
    if len(inputs) <= 1:
        return inputs[0]
    for i in range(len(inputs)+1):  ## (0,...5)
        s = make_empty_stack() # [] 
        first = push_stack(s, inputs[i])  #[1]
# push_stack pushes an item onto the stack s, returns the stack
        second = push_stack(s, inputs[i + 1]) ##[2,1]
        third = push_stack(s, inputs[i +2]) ##[2,1,+]
        f = pop_stack(third)  #Removes the top item of the stack #2
```

Here are some test cases

```
calculate((1, 2, '+', 3, '*')) ## 1+2 then * 3
calculate((1, 2, '+', 3, '/'))  ## (1 +2) / 3 = 1
calculate((28,)) # 28
calculate((1, 2, '*', 3, '-', 2, '*', 5, '+'))  ## ((1*2) - 3) * 2)+5 = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) provides convenient functions for most Python operators, including `+` and `*`:

```
import operator

ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub,
       '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.floordiv}
```

Now you can use the `ops` dictionary to implement operations on the stack:

```
def calculate(inputs):
    if not inputs:
        return
    s = make_empty_stack()
    for item in inputs:
        if item in ops:
            op2, op1 = pop_stack(s), pop_stack(s)
            res = ops[item](op1, op2)
            push_stack(s, res)
        else:
            push_stack(s, item)
    return pop_stack(s)
```

The code pops two items from the stack and passes them to the operator function, provided `item` is a valid operator. You need to invert the operands, however; you want to subtract the top-most stack item from the second item on the stack, not the other way around. Everything else is pushed to the stack instead.

Note that you need to create an empty stack just *once*, outside the loop.

Comment: I think there are some errors in you code. I ran it on python and they said TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @user3398505: Then you perhaps have operands that are not yet listed in `ops`, *or* some of your numbers are strings.

Comment: @user3398505: ah, reproduced and corrected; the result should be pushed, not the item. :-)

Comment: It did not work for this case calculate((1, 2, '*', 3, '-', 2, '*', 5, '+'))

Comment: returns 7 instead of 3

Comment: @user3398505: You know, you could try and follow along as to why that might be. :-) Corrected.